# Determine maximum allowed sample value in wave file in Python

Tags: python, audio, scipy, wav

`scipy.io.wavfile.read` returns the data as integers. To do audio processing, I'd like to convert these to floats. I want to allow any arbitrary bit depth in the input files, so I need to know the correct number by which to normalize the integer data. For example, for 16-bit `wav` files, I'd divide the integer array by `( 2**15 - 1 )`. But for 8-bit audio, I'd have to divide by `( 2**7 - 1 )`

Is there an easy way to get this bit-depth so I can convert all of these files into comparable float data? I feel like this is pretty basic, yet I can't seem to find it.

For a few reasons, I am limited, at least at the moment, to not installing more featureful packages such as `scikits`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.iinfo`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.iinfo.html) to get information about an integer data type.  For example, here's a 16 bit signed integer array:

```
In [338]: data = np.array([10, 20, -30], dtype=np.int16)

In [339]: ii = np.iinfo(data.dtype)

In [340]: ii.max
Out[340]: 32767

In [341]: ii.min
Out[341]: -32768

In [342]: ii.bits
Out[342]: 16
```

And here's an 8 bit unsigned integer array:

```
In [350]: data = np.array([10, 20, 200, 5], dtype=np.uint8)

In [351]: ii = np.iinfo(data.dtype)

In [352]: ii.max
Out[352]: 255

In [353]: ii.min
Out[353]: 0

In [354]: ii.bits
Out[354]: 8
```

Answer (score 0):

I've written a [tutorial](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/mgeier/python-audio/blob/master/audio-files/audio-files-with-wave.ipynb) on this and a helper function called [pcm2float()](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mgeier/python-audio/master/audio-files/utility.py) that does what you want.

Given a signal in a NumPy array `sig` and a target data type `dtype`, it simply does this:

```
sig.astype(dtype) / dtype.type(-np.iinfo(sig.dtype).min)
```

Comment: To support 8 bit / unsigned data as well, I've written: type_info = np.iinfo(x_native.dtype); type_range = type_info.max-type_info.min+1; type_offset = (type_info.max+type_info.min+1)/2; x = (x_native.astype(np.float) - type_offset) / (type_range/2);

Comment: That's great, thank you! I've just added support for unsigned integers to my [pcm2float() and float2pcm() functions](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mgeier/python-audio/master/audio-files/utility.py).